# Skype for linux beta 5.2.0.1 not working in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: skype

I can connect to Skype users who are on Windows during individual calls.

However, I am unable to connect to Skype users on other Linux machines for individual calls.

Also group calls are not working. 
I am not receiving the call at all.

Could someone help please?

Comment: I tried various ways and ended up using skype on web https://web.skype.com/en/

Comment: That's because you don't have the dependencies(programs that runs other programs) try installing `electron`, `libgnome-keyring`, `asar`, `nodejs`, `npm` and `python` or just downloading the .deb file and installing it with command prompt using `sudo dpkg -i skype_for_linux.deb` and then `sudo apt-get install -f`

Answer (score 4):

Skype for linux version 5.5 as downloaded from the site now works fine. But to install it you have to first purge any other Skypes you have including those you installed by mistake on top of an existing beta version.

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep 'skype'
skype-bin:i386                  deinstall
skypeforlinux                   install

sudo apt-get --purge remove skype-bin:i386
sudo apt-get --purge remove skypeforlinux

sudo dpkg -i [skype_deb_file].deb
```

Answer (score 2):

Using 17.04 64bit (Unity), I tried skypeforlinux 5.4.0.1 from official repo.
After the first run I closed it to the status indicator. Unfortunately, no indicator is shown, the 3 processes are running and need to be killed manually. If started again by dash, more instances get launched. No way to access the program.

I un-installed and re-installed to no avail.

So, I downloaded Ghetto-Skype, and installed it. It is workable; I still have no indicator, but, I can get to the window by dash (or lock the icon to launcher). Skype test calls are possible, chatting with other PC and Android, also.

Answer (score 1):

Skype for Linux is still in beta and it's filled with bugs.
Why don't you try the unofficial skype client [Ghetto Skype](https://github.com/stanfieldr/ghetto-skype)

It's way better than the official one, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Skype 5.x beta and the old Linux Skype are incompatible.

If you need to connect between two Linux machines, use one release of Skype.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not a tech expert. What do you mean when you say "..use one release of Skype"?

Comment: It means: use either the beta or the old stable Skype 4.2 on all Linux machines.